# ModHeader Extension with Axios Inteceptor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, interceptor, mod-headers

We are trying to create internal framework for mocking api calls. As part of that we are using **ModHeader** chrome extension to add custom headers for the request. Headers whatever we added in the extension not coming in axios interceptor, but in network request I can see all headers. Is there anyway to get headers in interceptor what we added in ModHeader extension?